# Split timestamps by date

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a series of timestamps in a PHP array.

How can I most efficiently separate these entries by the day they occurred?

Comment: please show what have you tried and the result

Comment: @diEcho Sorry, forgot to when I got the 10-minute lockout after creating the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they are unix timestamps, you can get just their date itself via something like this:

```
date('Yz', $yourTimestamp);
```

Which will show it as `2012251` for example. `Y` being the year, `z` being the day f the year and then use this for your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try with [DateTime format function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('@$timestamp');
echo $date->format('Y'); // will display Year
```

Comment: it is mentioned ['here'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). and this is not behaved as an error suppresor

Comment: Ok. I was confused when you had it outside of the string. Makes sense now!